# Shifted eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I realize this might seem like an amateur question, and maybe I am missing something here, but I truly need help here:

> What are the eigenvalues of $ I-A $, given those of the square matrix $A$?

I do not see how to work this out or if it is doable.
I certainly appreciate any help in showing me how to derive the expression here

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  Write down what it means for $\lambda$ to be an eigenvalue of $A$.  Then you can easily rework that into a statement about an eigenvalue of $I-A$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** Suppose $\bf v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, say, of eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then,
$$(I - A){\bf v} = I {\bf v} - A {\bf v} = {\bf v} - \lambda {\bf v} = \cdots .$$

Answer (score 3):

More general theorem.

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$
then for polynomial $p(A)$ the eigenvalue is $p(\lambda)$.

Answer (score 2):

If the ground field is algebraically closed, you can conjugate $A$ with $P$ such that it is upper triangular conjugating $I-A$ with $P$ gives an upper triangular matrix and the eigenvalues are $1-c$, $c$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

From the spectar theorem if l is eignevalue of A matrix then F(l) is eignevalue of F(A) matrix where F(x) is polynomial.You want to know the eignevalues of (I-A) if you set F(x)=1-x you will see that F(A)=I-A so the eignevalues of (I-A)=F(A) are F(l)=1-l where l is the eignevalue of A matrix.